# Ionic web app pages not opening with Ingress Controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have Ionic 5.0 Web App running on by Google K8s cluster. I am using Nginx Ingress Controller. Following ingress resource is configured for it to make it accessible:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /webapp/(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: webapp-frontend
              servicePort: 80
```

I am able to access the application using the following url:

- http://1.2.3.4/webapp            Working Fine and page is opening
- http://1.2.3.4/webapp/           Working Fine and page is opening
- http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login.     Not working, getting "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."

I am not getting what is wrong with the configuration here. Please help.

**####EDIT####**

My web application is deployed on pod and have following URL and this is exposed through service 'webapp-frontend':

- http://5.6.7.8/webapp

What i want is when user hit the url on browser following should happen:

- http://1.2.3.4/webapp --> should rewrite to http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login (this is happening)
- http://1.2.3.4/webapp/ --> should rewrite to http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login (this is happening)
- http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login --> should rewrite to http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login (this is NOT happening)

Comment: Which version of k8s are you running?

Comment: @OhHiMark its 1.16.8-gke.15.

Answer (score 0):

There are some thing you should look at:

- NetworkPolicy in the `extensions/v1beta1` API version is no longer served from Kubernetes version 1.16. You should use `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` instead.
- You are using the [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite) and basing on your config it should:

`http://1.2.3.4/webapp` rewrite to `http://1.2.3.4/`

`http://1.2.3.4/webapp/` rewrite to `http://1.2.3.4/`

`http://1.2.3.4/webapp/login` rewrite to `http://1.2.3.4/login`

You need to make sure that your Ingress is hitting the right URL. The config itself looks fine. The error might be in the logic behind the rewrite that you would like to implement. Refer to the [linked documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite) if needed. If it is still not working as intended, than please edit your question and provide more details (what should be rewrited where, etc).

This should address your issue from the Kuberentes side. Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: some how I missed your response and saw it today, I have edited my question about what should happen.